# Function not giving expected output Eos smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, eosio-code, float-point

My contract .Cpp part

```
void mainloan::adduwr(name acc_name, double interest, uint64_t loan_amount )
{
  print("Adding underwriter", acc_name);
  // require_auth( _self );

  uwr_table.emplace(get_self(), [&](auto &u) {
    u.acc_name = acc_name;
    u.interest_rate =interest;
    // u.loan_amount=loan_amount;
    u.giving_loan_amunt = loan_amount;
  });
}
```

.hpp part

```
 struct [[eosio::table]] underwriter_info
  {
    name acc_name;
    // std::vector<uint64_t> interest_rate;
    // std::vector<uint64_t> loan_amount; 
      double interest_rate;
      uint64_t giving_loan_amunt;
    auto primary_key() const
    {
      return acc_name.value;
    }
  };
```

```
  typedef eosio::multi_index<"underwriter"_n, underwriter_info> underwriter;

  underwriter uwr_table;


  [[eosio::action]] 
  void adduwr(name acc_name,double interest, uint64_t loan_amount);
```

Cleos call

```
guru@ubuntu:~/contracts/mainloan$ cleos --url http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80 push action microfinanc1 adduwr ['lender',8.6,10000] -p microfinanc1
executed transaction: 26b8218bbcd623430b440efecfcbb395cc5430f25d16900497e96c006c78977f  120 bytes  210 us
#  microfinanc1 <= microfinanc1::adduwr         {"acc_name":"lender","interest":"8.59999999999999964","loan_amount":10000}
>> Adding underwriterlender
warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet         ]
```

so the problem happens when i called the action

cleos --url http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80 push action microfinanc1 adduwr **['lender',8.6,10000]** -p microfinanc1

output from cleos

{"acc_name":"lender",**"interest":"8.59999999999999964"**,"loan_amount":10000}

so **8.6 is chnaged to 8.59999999999999964** why this is happening?
if anyone have any suggestion to give,please say it.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin floating-point types store values as finite binary fractions.
For technical specification, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).
For a human-readable explanation of the why, a good starting point is [The Floating-Point Guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

The number 8.6 is not representable as a finite binary fraction.
So, the `double` type stores the closest possible approximation instead, which is displayed to you as `8.59999999999999964`.

Comment: so what should i do for this,and this thing never happened with me till yesterday,actually yesterday i tried doing string to float conversion for the same code,instead of taking double rate argument i was taking string and then converting it into float,i had to do this due to some problem in float types in flutter .So i tried conversion & my data precision got reduced as it looks now,but i wanted precised data thats why i removed that code,but some how that code is still giving same output.Never faced this issue before

Comment: and also Even from flutter App tried to call the same action, and it gave the error saying **String is not type double** for  interest_rate 
& then i type cast it to double then it worked but 0.000001 got reduced 
@gassa please reply if u get these comments

Comment: @guruprakashgupta Naturally, if you want to use floating point, and got in trouble doing so, you should learn to better use floating point. Perhaps the links in this answer are a good start.